# Shafarevich's theorem about solvable groups as Galois groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, galois-theory

I am seeking references to any proofs of Shafarevich's theorem about solvable groups being Galois groups.

Comment: There is an old book by Shatz called "Pro-Finite Groups, Arithmetic, and Geometry" that has a proof.  I like the proof, but that may be a chocolate/vanilla thing.

Comment: Nice..i adore chocolate..

Comment: @aginensky Are you mistaking the theorem asked about in the question with Shafarevich's solution of the class tower problem? The table of contents in the google preview of Shatz's book doesn't list anything related to the inverse Galois problem for solvable groups. Besides that, as far as I know the much more recent paper given in mathphysicist's answer is the first correct proof of Shafarevich's theorem.

Comment: A proof is in Chapter IX, Section 6 of Neukirch, Schmidt, and Wignberg's "Cohomology of Number Fields".

Comment: I second @aginensky's recommendation for Shatz's lovely book, even if it doesn't contain a proof of the theorem (I don't have it to hand, so can't check).  :-)

Comment: It seems that Shafarevich's original proof contained an error regarding the prime number $2$, which was fixed by Schmidt/Wingberg.

Answer (score 7):

Also, the paper [Safarevic's Theorem on Solvable Groups as Galois Groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9809211) (freely available on arXiv) gives the proof.

Comment: My problem is that i cant understand that proof because i need to know what galois theory i need to understand it